# Express routing error, 'Router.post requires a callback function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Getting the error 
`Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`

I have checked a few of these errors here in SO and they do not pertain to what I have, at least not what I have seen.

I have this same style of syntax in another application and it's working just fine so I am not sure where this is going wrong. I have things importing and exporting correctly, or at least so I think.

index.js

```
const express         = require("express");
const bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
const partial         = require("express-partial");
const cors            = require('cors');
const mysql           = require('mysql');

const app = express() ;

app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(partial());

// ************************ROUTES*******************************
const longSplits            = require('./routes/longs.js')

app.use(longSplits);
```

longs.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const {
  newLongTrade
} = require('../splits/editLong.js')

//This is my first split route
router.post('/', newLongTrade);


module.exports = router;
```

Here is the "controller" part of the code.

```
const newLongTrade = (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body.data);
  res.send("Got it in the splits!");
}
module.exports = {
  newLongTrade
};
```

Comment: Can you verify that your required routes are correct? '../splits/editLong.js'

Comment: That was it! So simple I completely overlooked it.